# Set format property of field in linked table

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have an Access database as front end and SQL Server as back end. I have a link to SomeTable. I want to set then format property of SomeField to Yes/No and try this

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs("SomeTable").Fields("SomeField").Properties("Format").Value = "Yes/No"
```

I get an error:

> Property not found

Then I open my linked table in design mode, set the Format property of the field and save the table. Now, the code above runs with no error. It appears that I now have created the property. Is there a way to set the format property in code of a field on a freshly linked table?

Comment: You need to check if the property exists, and if not, you need to create it before attempting to set its value.

Comment: Thank you Kostas K. How do I create this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if the property exist, and create it if not.

See below.

```
On Error Resume Next

CurrentDb().TableDefs("SomeTable").Fields("SomeField").Properties("Format").Value = "Yes/No"

'if error, the property doesnt exist
If Err.Number = 3270 Then

    Dim prop As DAO.Property
    Set prop = CurrentDb().TableDefs("SomeTable").CreateProperty("Format")
    prop.Type = dbText
    prop.Value = "Yes/No"
        
    CurrentDb().TableDefs("SomeTable").Properties.Append prop

End If
```

Comment: @Erik A Thanks Erik.